# Connection error mariadb + wordpress with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose where I pick up two containers, one with mariadb and one with wordpress.

**The problem**

I receive a connection failure, apparently the user loses and cannot perform authentication.

> wp-mysql | 2019-08-09 13:21:16 18 [Warning] Aborted connection 18 to db: > 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.31.0.3' (This connection > closed normally without authentication)

**Situation**

When I go to http: // localhost: 8010 the wordpress service is available, but with an error connecting to the database.

The **docker-compose.yml** ...

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    container_name: wp-mysql
    image: mariadb
    volumes:
       - $PWD/data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345678
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    ports:
       - "3307:3306"
    networks:
       - my_net
    restart: on-failure

  wp:
    depends_on:
       - db
    container_name: wp-web
    volumes:
       - "$PWD/html:/var/www/html"
    image: wordpress
    ports:
       - "8010:80"
    environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
       - my_net

networks:
  my_net:
```

Error:

> wp-mysql | 2019-08-09 13:21:16 18 [Warning] Aborted connection 18 to db: > 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.31.0.3' (This connection > closed normally without authentication)

Where is the configuration error?

Why can't the wordpress container not use the user created in the mariadb container environment?

Comment: If this error occured only on linux machine, not on Mac Os then its probably the same issue i have faced, i did a work around by switching to mysql: 5.7 image instead of using mariadb image.

Comment: I had the same problem. In my case I was running Ubuntu into Windows. I had configured the volume into Windows file System. Then I changed to Ubuntu file system and it worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally solve it.

After going around and helped by the user @JackNavaRow the solution came out.

It was as simple as rebooting the system and deleting the volumes.

Pick up the containers and everything worked ok.

I leave it here in case anyone encounters this problem, that does not give more turns.

Comment: Please, could you detail how to fix the problem? I was not able to get it.

Comment: Lol, no restart. But simply removing the volume and starting over did the trick for as well.. Strange times..

Comment: Running `docker-compose down -v` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 10):

it may due to database files corrupted due to unexpected shutdown, you can delete the database volume

**warnning: this action will drop all your database data**

you could use `docker-compose down -v` to remove the volumes and then execute `docker-compose up -d` to bring it up

in your case, you are not using volume to store your database data, you can remove the data and try again

> rm -rf $PWD/data

Answer (score 0):

I changed my volume in my `docker-compose.yml`. This was to preserve data while trialing something.

```
volumes:
    - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

to the following

```
volumes:
    - ./data/mysql1:/var/lib/mysql
```

For whatever reason I encountered this error after doing this. To fix this error I ran `docker-compose down` and then deleted the folder `mysql1`. Then reran the `docker-compose up` command.